# Regex find the next specific tag eclipse

Tags: regex, eclipse

I am trying to replace / to null, like this

```
<h:graphicImage id="">
```

My code below.

```
<h:graphicImage id=""/>
<a>
<b>
<rich:componentControl target=""/>
<a>
<b>
</h:graphicImage>
```

The regex I used,

```
(<h:graphicImage[^>]*\s*)/>[\s\S]<rich:componentControl[^>]*)
```

It works if there no tags or content between the two tags but unfortunately in my code, there many tags between them. Any solution?

```
<h:graphicImage id=""/>
<rich:componentControl target=""/></h:graphicImage>
```

---

**Edit**

To be more clear about my question,
I would like to replace

```
<h:graphicImage id=""/>
```

to

```
<h:graphicImage id="">
```

when h:graphicImage tag has rich:componentControl this tag.

the code is like this below

```
<h:graphicImage id=""/>
<a>
<b>
<rich:componentControl target=""/>
<a>
<b>
</h:graphicImage>
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: You should use an XML parser (perhaps use XPath for match), trying to use regular expressions for XML is not a good idea.

Comment: Just a reminder: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 :-)

Comment: Hello there, I clarified my question again. So the problem is I have to replace the symbol /  when the h:graphicImage tag has rich:componentControl tag. The difficulty is the tags between them. I dont know how to ignore those tags<a><b>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use regex to parse XML or HTML
That being said, this should work (with ungreedy/Lazy flag set to true):

```
(<h:graphicImage[^>.]*)\/>[.\S\s]*(<rich:componentControl[^>]*)
```

Check out: https://regex101.com/r/gQ2vP7/1